# Rails3 display form_for form gives routing error if on other erb page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have a'Remove' button in a show erb of the trackers_controller.show:

```
    <%= form_for :user_tracker, :url => user_tracker_path,:method => :delete do |f| %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :tracker_id, :value =>  @tracker.id %>
        <%= f.submit :save, :value => 'Remove' %>
    <% end %>
```

This works fine and calls user_trackers_controller.destroy

The User models looks like:

```
  has_many :user_trackers
  has_many :trackers, :through => :user_trackers
```

If I put the exact same button in another erb I get this error:

```
   No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"user_trackers"}
```

I have a few different combinations like :html => {:method => :delete }

If I try it this way

```
<% current_user.user_trackers.each do |user_tracker| %>
    <%= user_tracker.tracker %>
    <%= form_for user_tracker,  :method => :delete  do |f| %>
        <%= f.submit :delete, :value => 'Remove' %>
    <% end %>
```

I get the same routing error

Here are the routes:

```
          user_trackers GET    /user_trackers(.:format)                user_trackers#index
                          POST   /user_trackers(.:format)                user_trackers#create
         new_user_tracker GET    /user_trackers/new(.:format)            user_trackers#new
        edit_user_tracker GET    /user_trackers/:id/edit(.:format)       user_trackers#edit
             user_tracker GET    /user_trackers/:id(.:format)            user_trackers#show
                          PUT    /user_trackers/:id(.:format)            user_trackers#update
                          DELETE /user_trackers/:id(.:format)            user_trackers#destroy
```

I do not understand, why will it not pick up that this is a destroy when in an unrelated erb?

**Edit:**
This is one seems to work but the html generates ids and classes like edit_user_tracker_7 but also the javascript to make it a delete so it  seems I still have something wrong:

```
    <%= form_for user_tracker, :url => user_tracker_path(user_tracker), :method => :delete do |f| %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :tracker_id, :value => user_tracker.tracker_id %>
        <%= f.submit :delete, :value => 'Remove from my portfolio' %>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: I see the error in the first case, where you had to call an object (form_for @user_tracker), or specify the id in the path (form_for :user_tracker, :url => user_tracker_path(@id).
But the second case with loop should work...

Comment: @MikhailD thanks - the first one works

Comment: @MikhailD thanks - the first one works I think because it's picking the id up from the controller/url - i.e. the page is http://localhost:3000/tracker/2 and the 2 is taken from there? But when it's in another page it fails. Can't get the second on to work

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, I think you're right why it worked in one case, and the other does not.
As for second you can try to specify the path? For example: form_for user_tracker, :url => user_tracker_path(user_tracker.id). However it should work without this ..

Comment: That seems to work thanks - see edit in question

Answer (score 0):

in first line it should be

```
:url => user_tracker_path(@user)
```

Its not a bug, he just have to know who to remove :) so he needs id (in REST).
Also `:method` should be in `:html`

```
:html => { :method => :delete }
```

or

```
html: { method: "delete" }
```

with 1.9+ notation.

full form_for

user_tracker_path(@user), :html => {:method => :delete} do |f| %>

ofc if in your case `@user` is current_user then you have to swap it :)

Sorry for typos & english i'm not native :)
Cheers!